# Creating new repository on central Windows/IIS web server

Tags: windows, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have recently started to configure Mercurial within my team as a proof of concept. We all use windows and develop Visual Studio and SQL Server based solutions/projects etc.

I have installed TortoiseHg on both mine and colleagues machine and also configured a central repository web server using IIS. I created a new repository on the web server and my colleague and I have been going through the motions, checking in pushing and pulling changes to.

My question is this. Say for example I have created a new repository locally and have been checking in code and now want to move it to the central server. My understanding is that I must first create the repository on the central server and then push my local code to it. But what methods are available for creating the remote repository.

I can rdp to the server, create a directory and then call hg init. I imagine I could do something similar with powershell remoting too. Any other suggestions, is possible to do this through TortoiseHg? I would also be interested to hear suggestions from a team based development best practice perspective too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an [admin tool](https://bitbucket.org/joshjcarrier/phphgadmin/wiki/Home) (site) I setup and worked into my central Hg website created under IIS.

Although I got it working (several months ago) we tend to create the central repos directly. In the end we found that we use UNC based file sharing much more than going through a web interface. I guess it depends upon if your team is distributed or not. If it is distributed then I would look at Bitbucket et al. to provide your central repo facilities, and then use their admin tools to setup and control the repos. As insurance set up a timed script to command line drive TortoiseHg to periodically pull all of your repos down for an on-site backup...

Also too, just to share. Take a look at VisualHg and my favorite HgScc to integrate with Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Keith, got visualHg on the go too thanks. Will also test UNC file sharing method too. Bitbucket or even Kiln are options in my eyes at least but I am unsure if others will be keen on code leaving the building :) Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

There are some other options besides phpHgAdmin Keith [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10802030/67988).

[RhodeCode](http://packages.python.org/RhodeCode/) (written in Python) has more features than phpMyAdmin. [SCM-Manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager/wiki/Home) (Java) even supports Git along with Mercurial. Both are open source.

You might have to use other servers than IIS for these to deploy, though.

Comment: Thanks for that, will have a good look in to Rhodecode. Quite like the look of kiln too.

Comment: RhodeCode supports git as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's unlikely you're running a sshd server since you're on Windows, but if you are you can remote-clone and remote-init repositories over ssh, like this:

```
hg clone mylocal ssh://host//absolute/path/to/repo
```

or

```
hg init ssh://host//absolute/path/to/repo
```

Comment: Thanks for that, definitely a possibility. Probably easier to push and  pull between developers too.